# Como usar la bocina de Android ignorando los Audifonos Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, soundpool

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que funciona como una alarma, el problema es que cuando hago sonar el audio que establecí como alerta si se tiene conectados los audífonos los usa como salida de audio, ¿como puedo hacer para que suene en la bocina principal ignorando los audífonos?

Así hago sonar el audio:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarma);
mp.start();
```

Gracias por la ayuda.